# Delphi - Sending Email which contains line feeds

Tags: delphi, mailto

Using Delphi 2010, I am trying to send email in which the BODY of the email needs to be multi-line.  I cannot get the multi-line part to work.  I have tried inserting #13, and #10, and '%0d'.  It either ignores and prints everything as one line, or I get an external exception.

Here is my source code.

```
  strEmail := 'address@domain.com';
  strSubject := 'Update Request: ';
  strBody := 'Line1 ' +#13 + 'Line 2';


  Param := 'mailto:' + strEmail + '?subject=' + strSubject + '&Body=' + strBody;
  Shellexecute(Main.Handle, 'open', PChar(Param), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

How do I get Line1 and Line2 on separate lines in the Body of my email?  You can assume that the only email client will be Outlook.  (Different versions may be used.)

Thanks,

GS

Comment: Have you tried `%0d%0a` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the mailto URL scheme [`RFC 2368`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt), you have to use the `%0D%0A` for line breaks. There's directly a note about it (removed double quotes):

> Also note that line breaks in the body of a message MUST be encoded
>   with %0D%0A.

Comment: This worked when I used %0D%0A, but if I use the double quotes, I get an external Exception EEFFACE.

Comment: Those double quotes are used in that document to distinguish a certain term, you must use it without them. I'll rather modify the quote in this post.

Answer (score 1):

As TLama noted, the RFC requires both a carriage return and a line feed to break lines in email.

Modify your third line to read:

```
strBody := 'Line1 ' + #13#10 + 'Line 2';
```

Any time I'm working on a program that makes more than trivial use of embedded carriage returns and line feeds, I declare a constant:

```
const
  CRFL = #13#10;
```

Knowing that I should use the constant instead of #13#10 throughout my code reduces the chance that I'll forget a part or enter them backwards.

Comment: You can just use sLineBreak instead of defining your own constant.

Answer (score 0):

adding

`'Line1 ' + #13#10 + 'Line 2'`

at TidMessage.Body.Text also worked for me.
outlook makes the rest, changing www to a link even with plain text.

thanks Eric.
it's good to Delphi 7 with Indy 9.